# Text in iPhone App get aliased in 2x Mode in ipad

Tags: iphone

I have an App for iPhone using high resolution images to make it work for both iPhone and iPad. But all the text get aliased in 2x mode in iPad.

Is that possible to let the App change the font size automatically in 2x Mode?

OR I have to detect device type and handle font size manually?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do anything about the font aliasing in the iPad 2x mode, nor can you know when the user enters the 2x mode.  It's nice that it uses the larger sized images, but consider that a bonus.

Comment: Thanks. For some app, they support all iPad, iPod and iPhone in iTunes. Is it correct that they have 3 separate App for each type of device and iTunes will select an appropriate one for the current device?

Comment: Yes, if you make an iPad specific version in a Universal binary then the iPad will render text and images as you expect.

Comment: the [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] value does change when the iPad goes to 2x mode. However, I don't think that increasing your font size is going to solve your issue: UI elements are rendered at 1x and scaled.