# detect iPad 2x button for iPhone app

Tags: iphone, ipad

Is there a way to detect that your iPhone app us running 2x/1x on an iPad?

I need to be able to detect the difference in points per inch for my app.

Comment: possible duplicate of [detecting iPhone app running on iPad in compatibility mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3242620/detecting-iphone-app-running-on-ipad-in-compatibility-mode)

Comment: @Josh, it's related, but not a duplicate. Recognizing that your iPhone app is running on an iPad, and detecting whether it's running at 1x or 2x, are two different things. Good link though; you'd certainly want to understand whether a 2x scale is associated with an iPhone4 retina display or an iPad 2x mode, before acting accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can detect the change by registering for the notification `_UIClassicApplicationWillChangeZoomNotificationName` and then handle the scale change using more or less the method outlined by @magma in his answer. `_UIClassicApplicationWillChangeZoomNotificationName` will tell you when the "2x"/"1x" button has been used to change the scale.

Answer (score 6):

Check the `scale` property:

```
[[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]
```

Here's a handy function:

```
+(BOOL) screenIs2xResolution {
  return 2.0 == [MyDeviceClass mainScreenScale];
}

+(CGFloat) mainScreenScale {
  CGFloat scale = 1.0;
  UIScreen* screen = [UIScreen mainScreen];
  if ([UIScreen instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(scale)]) {
    scale = [screen scale];
   }
  return scale;
}
```

Credits: http://www.markj.net/iphone-4-2x-graphics-scale-ipad/

See also: http://struct.ca/2010/high-res-graphics-in-cocos2d/

Comment: @madmik3 it does. Several developers support high-resolution graphics on iPhone apps running at 2x on an iPad.

Comment: I've added this code to my app and tested. It always reports a scale of 1.0.  So it is not working in my case.

Comment: This post claims it can't be done.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5644509/text-in-iphone-app-get-aliased-in-2x-mode-in-ipad

Comment: @madmik3 I have a working app that does exactly that - it works, at least on recent iOS versions. We're supporting high-resolution bitmaps on the iPad, although the app is iPhone-only. The article you linked refers to font rendering, which is something different.

Comment: Sorry, something must be different. I run the app. Print the scale. Hit the 2x button. Print the scale. Hit the 1x button. Print the scale. It always reads 1.0.  I can detect if it's iPad but not if it's running at 1x or 2x. That post goes on to say "nor can you know when the user enters the 2x mode". 

Sorry. don't think you are right.

Comment: Since iOS 4.2, scale is always 1.0 on the iPad, even in 2x mode.

Answer (score 2):

Since you cannot register for `_UIClassicApplicationWillChangeZoomNotificationName`, it seems to be an internal constant, what I did is:

Register for any Notification:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(changeZoom:) name:nil object:nil];
```

And then check the according values:

```
- (void)changeZoom:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    if ([[notification name] isEqualToString:@"_UIClassicApplicationWillChangeZoomNotificationName"])
    {
        NSLog(@"Zoom changed to %@", [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:@"_UIClassicIsZoomedUserInfoKeyName"] boolValue] == 0 ? @"1x" : @"2x");
    }
}
```