# How do I force iPad to 1x or 2x mode programmatically at startup?

Tags: ios, ipad

I can detect my iPad device running an iPhone app in 1x or 2x scale, thanks to an earlier post here: [detect iPad 2x button for iPhone app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6131913/detect-ipad-2x-button-for-iphone-app)

What I would like to do is to serialise this setting into `NSUserDefaults` when it is changed by the user so that force the app into 1x or 2x at startup. Currently the app always starts in 1x mode. Please note again I can detect when the user switches scale between 1x and 2x, my problem is to set the scale programmatically at startup.

It seems `[[UIScreen mainScreen] screen]` is read-only. However I know that some apps such as Google+ is capable of doing this. But how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, iOS seems to remember the "2x" setting for my apps. Perhaps it gets reset when debugging through Xcode. I would test with a release build and run it normally outside the debugger.

Comment: Spot on Mike. I was running it through debugger. That was the problem. The debugger always resets it to 1x mode at startup. Thanks a lot.